# Is there any way we can get Brevent/Shizuku running with Wireless Debugging on devices running below Android 11?

Tags: android, shell, adb, adbwireless

Well, it feels really great being able to use wireless debugging on an android device running android 11 or above but we can't do that like we do on devices running lower than android 11.
I mean we can't just use Brevent,Shizuku on devices running below android 11 just like we do it on devices running android 11 or above.
Is there any way we can get Wireless Debugging running through these applications on devices below android 11 ?
It would be really helpful.

I found ways where you can actually do these stuff with a PC with ADB over TCP connection.
But I want to run commands from apps like Brevent, Shizuku just like I do it on an android 11 device.
I can't rely that much on a PC. Well, I have no problems with PCs, I just want it to work just like I stated for people's benefits. People who have devices below android 11 can't run ADB commands with wireless debugging cause they don't have that. I'm fine with my android 13 but people with lower versions are suffering. Please help.

Comment: Wireless adb is a system feature only available on Android 11+. On older devices it is not available and there is nothing you can do to change this without updating the device to Android 11 or higher.